# Which device is working

Tags: linux, command-line, devices, dvb

I have one `dvb-t` and one `dvb-s` card in my system which are in

```
/dev/dvb/adapter0
```

and

```
/dev/dvb/adapter1
```

Is there a way to find out which card is currently working? and which one isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lsof` to see which processes are using a file. In your case:

```
$ lsof /dev/dvb/adapter0
$ lsof /dev/dvb/adapter1
```

Each call will give you a list of the processes having requested a handler (file descriptor) to your device. If nothing is printed, you can conclude that your device is not currently in use. Here's an example with `/dev/urandom`, used by Conky, Chromium and Thunderbird on my system:

```
$ lsof /dev/urandom
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
conky     ---- ----    3r   CHR    1,9      0t0 1034 /dev/urandom
chromium- ---- ----   55r   CHR    1,9      0t0 1034 /dev/urandom
thunderbi ---- ----   24r   CHR    1,9      0t0 1034 /dev/urandom
```

`r` (in the FD field) means that the processes have requested read access: the number just before that is their descriptor number.  `CHR` and `1,9` are the device type and major/minor numbers. `0t0` is the current file offset for that descriptor, and 1034 is the device file's inode number (on my system).

For more information about this output, see [`lsof(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof). By the way, `lsof` returns a different status code depending on whether it found processes for a file or not. This means you can use it quite simply in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if lsof /dev/dvb/adapter0 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Adapter 0 is in use."
elif lsof /dev/dvb/adapter1 > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Adapter 1 is in use."
else
    echo "No adapter is in use."
fi
```